# I want to sort my CatId in this order 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 but there is a catch that it first check allocationId last 14 digits if catid is same

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My query is this:-

```
SELECT m.allocationID,mt.CatId,mt.CatSName 
FROM msttransaction m,msttemp mt WHERE m.isPending='Y' 
AND m.allocationID IN ( 
    SELECT mt.AllocationId FROM msttemp WHERE mt.quarterId='010100001'
) ORDER BY SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
```

output:-

```
12980013120170919125006   1   A

12980013320170919125404   3   C

12980013420170919125603   4   D

12980013820170919130113   2   B

12980013920170919130315   3   C 

12980014020170919130519   4   D

12980013220170919130613   2   B

12980013720170919130722   1   A
```

In `129800` series last 14 digits is date and time. First I have to sort my output according to `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4` but first it check last 14 digits of `129800` of same catId that comes first which comes first.

Expected output

```
12980013120170919125006 1 A 
12980013820170919130113 2 B
12980013320170919125404 3 C
12980013420170919125603 4 D 
12980013720170919130722 1 A 
12980013220170919130613 2 B 
12980013920170919130315 3 C 
12980014020170919130519 4 D
```

Comment: "First i have to sort my output according to 1 2 3 4" - What do you mean?

Comment: what has 1 2 3 4 got to do with anything though? looks like you are ordering by your substring date

Comment: yup up to now i sort it by substring if i sort it by CatId then i will get A A B B C C D D but i want as i told in my expected output

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?

```
  ORDER BY m.CatId, SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
```

The point is to order first by that `CatId`, then order by the embedded datastamp in the `AllocationId`.

If it were me I'd be more formal about the datestamp ordering, by formally extracting it from your strings [using STR_TO_DATE() like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). This isn't strictly necessary, but good practice anyhow.

```
  ORDER BY m.CatId, STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'))
```

Plus, then you could use date manipulation like

```
  ORDER BY m.CatId, LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')))
```

to gather all the datestamps in a month together for ordering, or some such thing.

Here's an example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c87ee/6/0

Comment: O jones but  according to your query it gives same output A A B B C C D D

Comment: Look at my sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c87ee/6/0  It matches the output your question says you want. I don't understand your point about `AABBCCDD`. Please edit your question. By the way, every second you take figuring out a clear expression of your requirement saves you minutes in debugging later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a variable that will give you the order of the `CatId` when the result set *would have been ordered* by `CatId` and then the 14 last digits of the `AllocationId`. So in your example this variable would be either 1 or 2.

Once you have that variable value for each record, you can sort by that value first, and then by `CatId`:

```sql
select t.allocationId, CatId
from (
    select  t.*, 
            @rn := if(@CatId = CatId, @rn+1, if(@CatId := CatId, 1, 1)) rn 
    from (
            SELECT      m.allocationID, mt.CatId,mt.CatSName 
            FROM        msttransaction m,
            INNER JOIN  msttemp mt
                    ON  m.allocationID = mt.AllocationId
            WHERE       m.isPending='Y'
            AND         mt.quarterId='010100001'
            ORDER BY CatId, SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
         ) t,
         (select @CatId := -1, @rn := -1) init
    ) t
order by rn, CatId;
```